# too many values to unpack in genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a tsv file containing vibration data (with commas in place of dots for some silly reason, hence the converter). I'd like to generate numpy arrays from two of these channels, but get a "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" that I can't figure out.

in ipython (with pylab option):

```
In [171] import re

In [172]: def qdsub(s):
   .....:     return re.sub('\,', '.', str(s)[2:-1])
   .....:

In [173]: x, y = genfromtxt('QD1_short.tsv', delimiter='\t', usecols=(0, 1), 
   .....: unpack=True, skip_header=13, converters={0:qdsub, 1:qdsub}, 
   .....: skip_footer=2, dtype=float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-177-e17389233ac3> in <module>()
        1 x, y = genfromtxt('QD1_short.tsv', delimiter='\t', usecols=(0, 1), 
        2 unpack=True, skip_header=13, converters={0:qdsub, 1:qdsub},
  ----> 3 skip_footer=2, dtype=float)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Apparently I can't answer my own question yet, but the problem is solved, see comment on User's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the converter, which apparently should return a float

```
def qdsub(s):
    return float(re.sub('\,', '.', str(s)[2:-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the problem:

```
x, y = ge...
```

Try

```
v = ge...
```

Example:

```
>>> a, b = [1,2,3,4]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    a, b = [1,2,3,4]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: well, `v = genfromtxt(...` certainly returns something, without errors, problem is it's a seemingly useless `array([('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ..., `  
  
using only one column, I get a neat array of floats, and I want to get two of those. I've done it before with x, y = loadtxt(... but the footer of this tsv means I cannot go that route

Comment: Apparently, the problem was in the converter. Modified it to `return re.sub('\,', '.', str(s)[2:-1])` and now it all works stellar. Seems strange that it was ok on single columns before though. Oh well..

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) of `numpy.genfromtxt` says:

> **unpack :** bool, optional
>
> ```
> If True, the returned array is transposed, so that arguments may be unpacked 
> using x, y, z = loadtxt(...)
> ```

My best guess is that you should try to wrap the `genfromtxt` inside `loadtxt`:

```
from numpy import loadtxt, genfromtxt
(...)

x, y = loadtxt(genfromtxt('QD1_short.tsv', delimiter='\t', usecols=(0, 1), 
                          unpack=True, skip_header=13, converters={0:qdsub, 1:qdsub}, 
                          skip_footer=2, dtype=float))
```